# How to serialize models with multiple foreign keys?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to serialize data in the format given below.I'm new to django-rest framework.I am working in a varsity project.So, little help will be appreciated.

```py
    {
      {
      "Series_name":"something",
      "Home_team":"anything",
      "Away_team":"sbh",
       "players":[
                {
                   "id":"1",
                    ...
                }
                {
                    "id":"2",
                    ...
                }
        ]

      },

      {
      "Series_name":"something2",
      "Home_team":"anything",
      "Away_team":"sbh",
       "players":[
                {
                   "id":"1",
                    ...
                }
                {
                    "id":"1",
                    ...
                }
        ]

       }

    }
```

I have tried this.But this doesn't give satisfactory result.In fact it returns empty set.

```py
    class PlayersSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = Players
            fields = ['name', 'country', 'image', 'role', 'credit']

    class SeriesListSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = SeriesList
            fields = '__all__'


    class SeriesSquadsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        players = PlayersSerializer2(many=True, read_only=True)
        series = SeriesListSerializer2(many=True, read_only=True)

        class Meta:
            model = SeriesSquads
            fields = ['series', 'players']
```

these are the models I'm working with.I've 3 models SeriesList,Series_Squads and Players.Series_sqauds has unique pairs (Series_name,Players).It has two foreign keys pointing objects of SeriesList and Players.

```py
    class SeriesList(models.Model):
        Series_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, 
                   unique=True,primary_key=True)
        No_of_matches = models.IntegerField()
        Home_team = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        Away_team = models.CharField(max_length=250)


    class SeriesSquads(models.Model):
        Series_name = models.ForeignKey(SeriesList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Squad_player = models.ForeignKey(Players, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Players(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=250)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        image = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        role = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        credit = models.FloatField(default=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get user of `SerializerMethodField` to get your ForeignKey related objects into your serializer. Update your serializer so that:

```py
class PlayersSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Players
        fields = ['name', 'country', 'image', 'role', 'credit']


class SeriesSquadsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    players = PlayersSerializer2(many=True, read_only=True)
    Series_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    Home_team = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    Away_team =  = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SeriesSquads
        fields = ['players']

    def get_Series_name(self, obj):
        return obj.Series_name.Series_name

    def get_Home_team(self, obj):
        return obj.Series_name.Home_team

    def get_Away_team(self, obj):
        return obj.Series_name.Away_team
```

Comment: 'Players' object is not iterable .. i'm getting this error ..can you please help me with this?

Comment: As you defined players as foreign key in your model, it cannot have more than one in your series squad object. Hence you need to delete ```many=True``` from your serializer.

Comment: Actually i wanted to get all the players in a serieslist .But if i remove many=True ,it only give all the squadplayers objects. can you please tell me how  I can  get all the players in a serieslist ?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is you must have only one players object in your serializer because in your models; ```players``` is defined as a ```ForeignKey```. If you have user ManyToMany relation, you would have many players in your serializers.

Comment: thanks for your help..it worked.. as i'm new to django, i didn't understand it at first..